# Why vertical orientation does not render images vertically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-alignment

My .xml file has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/image_list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, the phone renders images as follows:

[image]

**Why?**

Comment: I think you have to share with us your adapter and adapter item layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting a `LayoutManager` for the `RecyclerView`? See this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager)).

> **setLayoutManager**
>
> void setLayoutManager (RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout)
>
> Set the RecyclerView.LayoutManager that this RecyclerView will use.
>
> In contrast to other adapter-backed views such as ListView or GridView, RecyclerView allows client code to provide custom layout arrangements for child views. These arrangements are controlled by the RecyclerView.LayoutManager. A LayoutManager must be provided for RecyclerView to function.